# Why do I have to specify data type each time in C to printf() and scanf()?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, printf, scanf

As you can see from the code snippet below, I have declared one `char` variable and one `int` variable. When the code gets compiled, it must identify the data types of variables `str` and `i`.

Why do I need to tell again during scanning my variable that it's a string or integer variable by specifying `%s` or `%d` to `scanf`? Isn't the compiler mature enough to identify that when I declared my variables?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char str [80];
  int i;

  printf ("Enter your family name: ");
  scanf ("%s",str);  
  printf ("Enter your age: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%x`, `%d`, `%s` are all format-specifiers that "tell" `printf()` how to display the data; i.e. whether the stream of bits is to be displayed as a hexadecimal number or as a decimal integer or the ASCII representation. Data is data is data. :-) The programmer (using printf) is free to interpret it however he wishes to.

Comment: See Yu Hao's answer ... the problem is that printf and scanf are varargs functions, which means that their parameters do not have static types. And C is weakly typed ... there is no runtime type info that the functions can examine; the format serves that purpose.

Comment: what about my answer about format specifiers? and do you think `stdio.h` is not necessary to use `scanf()` as Mr @mvp suggest?

Comment: Who says the format is always a string literal like `"%s"` that the compiler could analyze? It can be a string with a computed value. There's no way a compiler could analyze those at compile time.

Comment: Whether or not compiler maturity has anything to do with language features, it's hard for anyone to answer questions about your compiler when you haven't said which one it is.

Comment: Although the limitations of the C language and the fact that you can create the format string at runtime mean that for `printf`, `scanf`, and friends you will always need to specify the type again, if the format string is hardcoded, some compilers will at least verify for you that the types match: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat-286

Comment: @TheCodeArtist If this is enough to turn a programmer off of C, we don't want them anyway.

Comment: The point is valid though, there is no real reason a compiler couldn't see "%?" (where %? is a compiler extension) and use typeof(next_arg_in_list) to guess what '?' _should_ be replaced with, with a bonus for using context like "0x" to specify hex etc...

Comment: That comment two above this one is possibly the worst comment I've ever seen on SO, in so many ways ...

Comment: @technosaurus First, that suggestion, which is a way to provide runtime type information, is quite different from the OP's, which would do away with the format argument entirely. Second, there is a real reason: the C language standard doesn't support any such thing. Perhaps some day it will.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Because there's no portable way for a variable argument functions like `scanf` and `printf` to know the types of the variable arguments, not even how many arguments are passed.

See C FAQ: [How can I discover how many arguments a function was actually called with?](http://c-faq.com/varargs/nargs.html)

---

This is the reason there must be at least one fixed argument to determine the number, and maybe the types, of the variable arguments. And this argument (the standard calls it `parmN`, see C11([ISO/IEC 9899:201x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1539.pdf)) §7.16 *Variable arguments* ) plays this special role, and will be passed to the macro `va_start`. In another word, you can't have a function with a prototype like this in standard C:

```
void foo(...);
```

Comment: +1 for the only answer here that recognizes what the issue is ... lack of static types for varargs.

Comment: Also, as mentioned in comments above, there is not a one-to-one correspondence between the var type and the `printf` format "type."

Comment: @MarkHu True, but that's more like a result than a reason. Anyway, think about this, why the format specifier of `printf` uses `%f` to output `double`, what about `float`?

Comment: The second paragraph, added after my comment above, is quite unfortunate and wholly wrong. The first argument is needed only because there's no other way to specify the starting address of the arguments in a stack-based implementation without adding an additional language feature. There are many other ways of determining the argument types, including globals, and there's no particular reason that type info has to be in the *first* argument ... you could have, say, 5 arguments of known type before starting arguments of unknown type, and you still have to use `va_arg` for all of them.

Comment: @JimBalter I didn't say *first* argument anywhere, did I? `parmN`, by definition, is the rightmost parameter before `...`, it doesn't have to be the *first* argument. And it is needed in standard C.

Comment: @YuHao Yes, I goofed on the *first* argument but the rest is right ... parmN is needed to get an address into the stack; it has nothing to do with how the types are determined, which is up to the function ... and the types certainly don't have to be derived from parmN. Of course it is "needed" in standard C, as it is part of the standard ... I was on X3J11 and know exactly why ... it was a standardization of existing varargs mechanisms in existing implementations, sanctified by the C compiler vendors who dominated the committee.

Comment: @JimBalter I meant a standard C variable argument function must have a `parmN` argument syntactically, even if you use other methods to determining the type info.

Comment: You wrote "This is the reason ... to determine the number, and maybe the types ...". That simply is *not* the reason. You can't tell the number of parameters from parmN. For some functions, for instance, the last parm is NULL or otherwise an end indicator.

Comment: Finally, the second paragraph has nothing to do with the question ... the first paragraph covers that.

Answer (score 28):

The reason why the compiler can not provide the necessary information is simply, because the compiler is not involved here. The prototype of the functions doesn't specify the types, because these functions have variable types. So the actual data types are not determined at compile time, but at runtime.
The function then takes one argument from the stack, after the other. These values don't have any type information associated with it, so the only way, the function knows how to interpret the data is, by using the caller provided information, which is the format string.

The functions themselves don't know which data types are passed in, nor do they know the number of arguments passed, so there is no way that `printf` can decide this on it's own.

In C++ you can use operator overloading, but this is an entire different mechanism. Because here the compiler chooses the appropriate function based on the datatypes and available overloaded function.

To illustrate this, `printf`, when compiled looks like this:

```
 push value1
 ...
 push valueN
 push format_string
 call _printf
```

And the prototype of `printf` is this:

```
int printf ( const char * format, ... );
```

So there is no type information carried over, except what is provided in the format string.

Comment: Nice explanation of the mechanism in general and then more technical language.

Comment: And a good use of having a string as a format is that the format can actually come from various sources: it's not hardcoded in the source code. You could even ask the user to supply their own format string or use it with gettext to change the pattern order.

Comment: @Max-P, yes, that's definitely an advantage, but also a dangerous pitfill. :) And of course, you would have to write some wrapper anyway, because if you can provide the format string on the commandline (so to speak) you must ensure that the appropriate arguments are also provided.

Comment: That `push` ... `push` `call` sequence is one possible way to implement a `printf` call. The actual calling convention is not specified by the C standard (it's typically specified by the ABI for the platform). For example, some arguments might be passed in registers, and they can be passed in any order.

Comment: @KeithThompson, I know. It depends on the implementation and optimizations. However, no matter how it is done, there is no type information asssociated, only the raw binary values, specified by the caller.

Answer (score 14):

`printf` is not an [intrinsic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function). It's not part of the C language per se. All the compiler does is generate code to call `printf`, passing whatever parameters. Now, because C does not provide [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) as a mechanism to figure out type information at run time, the programmer has to explicitly provide the needed info.

Comment: @Kevin Panko Thanks for your nice edit! I am still a noob as far as editing is concerned.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `printf` is not a language feature or special in any way, hence the compiler is not obligated to optimise it

Comment: @Tarik If `printf` is not part of the C language, then where is it actually implemented? By the OS?

Comment: @TejasChandrashekhar Very late answer to your question, but here it is: What makes up a language is the keywords, the syntax and the resultant behavior. printf is but a function implemented partly in C and eventually doing a system call to get the formatted bytes into a file or on the screen. The source code for printf can be found here: https://code.woboq.org/linux/linux/arch/x86/boot/printf.c.html

Answer (score 13):

Compiler may be smart, but functions `printf` or `scanf` are stupid - they do not know what is the type of the parameter do you pass for every call. This is why you need to pass `%s` or `%d` every time.

Comment: How could you make these functions smart? Reflection is not supported in C.

Comment: In `C++` you can: something like `cin >> counter`; or `cout << str`; work as expected. But in `C` you can't do that, that's why string formats like `%d` were invented.

Comment: In C++ the example of cin/cout is not appropriate. The reason why this works is because of overloading, so the compiler can decide at compiletime which function it will provide for the call. This is an entirely differente mechanism then varargs. For the user it looks similar, but technically it isn't.

Comment: That's because C++ supports operator overloading which ultimately means that you have a method for << string, another one for << int and so on... In a procedural language like C that would be equivalent to having print_str, print_int... functions.

Comment: I suppose theoretically the correct `%x` could be inserted by the compiler.

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but the format of the string is unknown. After all, you can pass in an arbitrary string. What could be done theoretically at compile time is essentially to parse the format string like printf does, and check if the paraemters are correct. But then you would have to provide this for all standard functions. But then again, you can print i.e. a string as a pointer or a string.

Comment: Even that would not work: nothing stops somebody from trying to pass something more complicated than `int`, `double` or `char*`: for example, if variable is pointer to some weird structure.

Comment: @Timo Theoretically,  anything could be done, but that would be changing the low level nature of C and the flexibility that comes with it. It would not be C anymore... But why bother? C++ already exists.

Answer (score 10):

The first parameter is a **format string**. If you're printing a decimal number, it may look like:

- `"%d"` (decimal number)
- `"%5d"` (decimal number padded to width 5 with spaces)
- `"%05d"` (decimal number padded to width 5 with zeros)
- `"%+d"` (decimal number, always with a sign)
- `"Value: %d\n"` (some content before/after the number)

etc, see for example [Format placeholders on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders) to have an idea what format strings can contain.

Also there can be more than one parameter here:

`"%s - %d"` (a string, then some content, then a number)

Answer (score 8):

> Isn't the compiler matured enough to identify that when I declared my
>   variable?

No.

You're using a language specified decades ago. Don't expect modern design aesthetics from C, because it's not a modern language. Modern languages will tend to trade a small amount of efficiency in compilation, interpretation or execution for an improvement in usability or clarity. C hails from a time when computer processing time was expensive and in highly limited supply, and its design reflects this.

It's also why C and C++ remain the languages of choice when you really, really care about being fast, efficient or close to the metal.

Comment: That's a weird comment to put on my answer. I never claimed otherwise.

Comment: yes I'm sorry, I wrote it into the wrong open tab. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` as prototype `int scanf ( const char * format, ... );` says stores given data according to the parameter format into the locations pointed by the additional arguments.

It is not related with compiler, it is all about syntax defined for `scanf`.Parameter format is required to let `scanf` know about the size to reserve for data to be entered.

Answer (score 4):

GCC (and possibly other C compilers) keep track of argument types, at least in some situations. But the language is not designed that way.

The `printf` function is an ordinary function which accepts variable arguments. Variable arguments require some kind of run-time-type identification scheme, but in the C language, values do not carry any run time type information. (Of course, C programmers can create run-time-typing schemes using structures or bit manipulation tricks, but these are not integrated into the language.)

When we develop a function like this:

```
void foo(int a, int b, ...);
```

we can pass "any" number of additional arguments after the second one, and it is up to us to determine how many there are and what are their types using some sort of protocol which is outside of the function passing mechanism.

For instance if we call this function like this:

```
foo(1, 2, 3.0);
foo(1, 2, "abc");
```

there is no way that the callee can distinguish the cases. There are just some bits in a parameter passing area, and we have no idea whether they represent a pointer to character data or a floating point number.

The possibilities for communicating this type of information are numerous. For example in POSIX, the `exec` family of functions use variable arguments which have all the same type, `char *`, and a null pointer is used to indicate the end of the list:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void my_exec(char *progname, ...)
{
  va_list variable_args;
  va_start (variable_args, progname);

  for (;;) {
     char *arg = va_arg(variable_args, char *);
     if (arg == 0)
       break;
     /* process arg */
  }

  va_end(variable_args);
  /*...*/
}
```

If the caller forgets to pass a null pointer terminator, the behavior will be undefined because the function will keep invoking `va_arg` after it has consumed all of the arguments. Our `my_exec` function has to be called like this:

```
my_exec("foo", "bar", "xyzzy", (char *) 0);
```

The cast on the `0` is required because there is no context for it to be interpreted as a null pointer constant: the compiler has no idea that the intended type for that argument is a pointer type. Furthermore `(void *) 0` isn't correct because it will simply be passed as the `void *` type and not `char *`, though the two are almost certainly compatible at the binary level so it will work in practice.  A common mistake with that type of `exec` function is this:

```
my_exec("foo", "bar", "xyzzy", NULL);
```

where the compiler's `NULL` happens to be defined as `0` without any `(void *)` cast.

Another possible scheme is to require the caller to pass down a number which indicates how many arguments there are. Of course, that number could be incorrect.

In the case of `printf`, the format string describes the argument list. The function parses it and extracts the arguments accordingly.

As mentioned at the outset, some compilers, notably the GNU C Compiler, can parse format strings at compile time and perform static type checking against the number and types of arguments.

However, note that a format string can be other than a literal, and may be computed at run 
time, which is impervious to such type checking schemes. Fictitious example:

```
char *fmt_string = message_lookup(current_language, message_code);

/* no type checking from gcc in this case: fmt_string could have
   four conversion specifiers, or ones not matching the types of
   arg1, arg2, arg3, without generating any diagnostic. */
snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, fmt_string, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because this is the only way to tell the functions (like `printf` `scanf`) that which type of value you are passing. for example-

```
int main()
{
    int i=22;
    printf("%c",i);
    return 0;
}
```

this code will print character not integer 22. because you have told the printf function to treat the variable as char.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` and `scanf` are I/O functions that are designed and defined in a way to receive a control string and a list of arguments.

The functions does not know the type of parameter passed to it , and Compiler also cant pass this information to it.

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question as far as I can make out.

Answer (score 0):

Because in the printf you're not specifying data type, you're specifying data format. This is an important distinction in any language, and it's doubly important in C.

When you scan in a string with with `%s`, you're not saying "parse a string input for my string variable." You *can't* say that in C because C doesn't have a string type. The closest thing C has to a string variable is a fixed-size character array that happens to contain a characters representing a string, with the end of string indicated by a null character. So what you're really saying is "here's an array to hold the string, I promise it's big enough for the string input I want you to parse."

Primitive? Of course. C was invented over 40 years ago, when a typical machine had at most 64K of RAM. In such an environment, conserving RAM had a higher priority than sophisticated string manipulation.

Still, the `%s` scanner persists in more advanced programming environments, where there are string data types. Because it's about scanning, not typing.

Comment: No, each format specifier does specify the required type of the argument. `%s` requires an argument of type `char*` (which must be a pointer to a string). `%d` requires an argument of type `int`. `%x` and `%o` require and argument of type `unsigned int`. And so forth. `%s` is a bit different in that it processes data that the argument points to. Oh, and the end of a string is not indicated by `NULL`; that's a null *pointer* constant. It's indicated by a null *character*, `'\0'`.

Comment: First off, you're misusing the word "requires". That implies that you get an error if you provide the wrong data type. You get a warning, no more. The %s _expects_ ``char *`` but you still compiles if you provide something else. // You're right about the NULL though, I'll change that.

Comment: I didn't mean the word "requires" to imply that a diagnostic is required. In fact, the behavior is undefined, and providing the wrong type is erroneous. (It doesn't require a diagnostic because that would be impossible in general; the format string needn't be a string literal.) By providing a `"%s"` or `"%d"` format, you, the programmer, are specifying that you will provide a `char*` or `int`, respectively, as the corresponding argument.

Comment: "That implies that you get an error if you provide the wrong data type" -- No it doesn't. This is wrong and so, for the most part, is your answer.

Comment: @JimBalter A comment that tells me I'm wrong without telling me why is not very useful.

Comment: Read the C standard to learn about requirements on programs and implementations. Diagnostics need only be provided for constraint errors, but there are many other requirements, such as that `%s` requires an argument of type `char*`, as Keith correctly stated.

Comment: The question at hand is "why does C do things this way?" Which has nothing to do with the standard -- the language was around before there were standards for it. If you want to understand the design of a language, you need to read its founding documentation. In this case, a good place to start is Kernighan & Richie.