# Working of printf() function in C (Only Variable number of Arguments)

Tags: c++, c

I am asking this question to understand the working of **printf** as a function which is accepting variable length arguments.

I am learning the variable number of argument concept from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/) and what confused me is the datatype passing in **va_arg(va_list,datatype)**. I mean they are mentioning one data type here. What about the case where we need to pass arguments with different datatypes. The same thing is done in **printf** function.

How exactly printf figures out the different type of argument types. As per my thinking they must be checking every % symbol in the first const char* argument and after that the token checking for particular datatypes.

Comment: quick link to help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457656/understanding-the-hardware-of-printf

Comment: @Jayesh thanks for the link but I am not looking for the hardware level. Only the datatype identification in va_arg(). I mean how they actually identify a particular datatype among multiple different datatype arguments

Comment: Yes it checks the `%X` to see what data type or flags to use. Without this, it cannot know. The only way is if you use C++'s variadic templates.

Comment: `printf` knows the type only from the format specifier. Relevant: [Why do I have to specify data type each time in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203636/why-do-i-have-to-specify-data-type-each-time-in-c).

Comment: Btw, if you are writing in C++ use streams instead of legacy functions from C

Comment: "I mean they are mentioning one data type here" -- because va_arg only fetches one argument. Each va_arg can fetch a different type. printf of course uses the type specified in the % format to select the type. open source printf is available ... google for it.

Answer (score 2):

The Following Variable argument list function explains you how the `printf` will work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void foo(char *fmt, ...) // This Function works like same as printf
{
    va_list ap;
    int d;
    char c, *s;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    while (*fmt)
        switch (*fmt++) {
           case 's':              /* string */
               s = va_arg(ap, char *);
               printf("string %s\n", s);
               break;
           case 'd':              /* int */
               d = va_arg(ap, int);
               printf("int %d\n", d);
               break;
           case 'c':              /* char */
               /* need a cast here since va_arg only
                  takes fully promoted types */
               c = (char) va_arg(ap, int);
               printf("char %c\n", c);
               break;
        }
   va_end(ap);
}

main()
{
// call the foo function here
// like foo("%d%s%c",3,"hai",'a');
}
```

For more reference see the man page of [va_arg](http://linux.die.net/man/3/va_arg)

It won't support `char` and `float` values, so we need to typecast it.
For `float` you need to typecast the `double` values.

Comment: It's better if you could make the _man page of `va_arg`_ a link.

Comment: That would be foo("dsc" not foo("%d%s%c"

Comment: Also, either the order of function declarations has to be reversed or you'll need a prototype of your function above.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is a function, not a macro. It is defined as

```
int printf(const char *, ...)
```

and has variable number of arguments.

`printf` use string to define number of arguments passed. Each % is used to move towards the stack and retrieve arguments.

So, if you passed

```
"%d %d %d", 1, 2
```

then 1, 2, and arbitrary value would be displayed. That is bad: you can walk down the stack using this function.

When passed

```
"%d %d", 1, 2, 3
```

then 1 and 2 would be displayed. And behaviour is undefined: usually __cdecl calling convention is used, so stack wouldn't be corrupted because cleaned by caller.

Comment: If want to check something refer to http://www.cplusplus.com. They usually have explanation for all libraries.

Comment: @anujpradhan "i think printf got derived from _printf" -- Not sure what you mean by that, but ... no. printf has existed since the earliest days of C and was not derived from some other function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it checks the %X to see what data type or flags to use. Without this, it cannot know. The only way is if you use C++'s variadic templates. Other than that, C does it like below..

This example uses `fwrite` to write the data to `stdout`.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>

void C_Printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int fmtLength = strlen(fmt);
    va_list VariableArgs;
    va_start(VariableArgs, fmt);

    for (int I = 0; I < fmtLength; I++)
    {
        if (fmt[I] == '%')
        {
            switch(tolower(fmt[++I]))
            {
                case 'f':
                {
                    double d = va_arg(VariableArgs, double);
                    fwrite(&d, sizeof(double), 1, stdout);
                }
                break;

                case 'i':
                case 'd':
                {
                    int i = va_arg(VariableArgs, int);
                    fwrite(&i, sizeof(int), 1, stdout);
                }
                break;

                case 's':
                {
                    const char *str = va_arg(VariableArgs, const char *);
                    fwrite(&str[0], sizeof(char), strlen(str), stdout);
                }
                break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
            fwrite(&fmt[I], sizeof(char), 1, stdout);
    }
    va_end(VariableArgs);
}

int main()
{
    C_Printf("%s", "hello there");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the source code of `printf`  in some [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) standard C library implementation, e.g. [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/). I find `musl-libc`  very readable, look inside [src/stdio/printf.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/printf.c) then [src/stdio/vfprintf.c](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/stdio/vfprintf.c) (where the real work is done). Of course it uses `va_arg` according to the format control string (see [stdarg(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdarg.3.html). Notice that `va_arg`  is implemented *inside* the compiler, thru `__builtin_va_arg`  in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) . GCC also has builtin support for `printf`